# Swift Avplayer - Stop all other tableviewcells from playing, when 'Play' is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

My home page is a table view and each cell has a play button (when clicked an `AVAudioPlayer` instance is created). The problem is I can click Play on multiple cells and they will all play simultaneously. I am trying to figure out how to pause the other cells when any Play button is clicked.

Here is my play button code from my `TableViewCell` file:

```
@IBAction func playButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if self.audioPlayer != nil {
        if self.audioPlayer.isPlaying {
            self.audioPlayer.pause()
            self.playbutton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bluePlay"), for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            self.audioPlayer.play()
            self.playbutton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bluePause"), for: .normal)
        }
        return
    }
    do {
        self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: self.audioFile!)
        self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        self.audioPlayer.delegate = self as? AVAudioPlayerDelegate
        self.audioPlayer.play()
        self.playbutton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bluePause"), for: .normal)

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("audioSession error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    } catch {
        print(#line, error.localizedDescription)
    }
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector: (#selector(HomeTableViewCell.updateProgress)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

I have been trying protocols, trying to edit the `TableViewVC` and the `TableViewCellVC`, but I can't quite get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have an audio player inside one cell, you need a way of informing ALL the other cells that an audio player has been clicked. You can achieve this by creating a closure inside each `UITableViewCell` and assigning it inside of `cellForRow`. Whenever the play button is clicked, the closure will get fired and inside your `UIViewController` you will iterate over all visible cells and pause them before playing the player in your clicked cell. Something like this:

```
class CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell{

    var playButtonTapped : (()->())?
    @IBAction func playButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
         playButtonTapped?()
         //rest of the code comes below
    }
}


class TableViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        ....
        cell.playButtonTapped = {
             for tempCell in tableView.visibleCells{
                 if let ultraTempCell = tempCell as? CustomTableViewCell, ultraTempCell != cell /* or something like this */{
                    //pause the player here
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

**Alternatively**, what you can do is, instead of having a player inside each cell, just make a player inside the `UIViewController` and depending on the cell clicked, just change the song inside.

Comment: Hm this seems to be working,I paused the player and changed the image in the closure. However , it doesnt work if I click on the same cell twice. IE playing one cell, click play button on another, cell - it works and the first one paused (and its button turned to play) but, if i Click the current one Im listening to again, it isnt pausing like normal, it keeps playing. PS thank you so much for taking time out of your day to help me

Comment: Yes that is a valid bug but easy to fix. Maybe try checking the `indexPaths` inside the closure! Just skip pausing the cell that was tapped inside of `cellForRow`. Check the edit for a hint.

Comment: Thank you sir , I got it to work perfectly, you helped me a ton =) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can try to call `self.audioPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)` after calling `self.audioPlayer.pause()`, so your code would look something like this.

```
if self.audioPlayer != nil {
    if self.audioPlayer.isPlaying {
        self.audioPlayer.pause()
        self.audioPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
        self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        self.playbutton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bluePlay"), for: .normal)
    }
    else {
        self.audioPlayer.play()
        self.playbutton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bluePause"), for: .normal)
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Value of type 'AVAudioPlayer' has no member 'replaceCurrentItem'
Thank so much for taking time to help

Comment: Oh, didn't notice it's an `AVAudioPlayer`. With it you can try to 
1) confirm to the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`
2) add `func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {}`
3) call  `self.audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(self.audioPlayer, successfully: true)` when you want it to stop

P.S. I will edit an answer if that works for your case

Comment: Thank you. The answer above actually worked out perfectly but thanks again for helping.